# How does Integer.parseInt works

Tags: java

The method public static int parseInt(String str)
and
public static int parseInt(String str, int redix)

How does it work?

& what is the difference between them?

Comment: You can read the source code of these methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String,int%29). And the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

As for the difference:

The first assumes the String to be a decimal representation, while the second expects another parameter which is the base of the representation (binary, hex, decimal etc.)

( `parseInt(String str)` is implemented as return `parseInt(str, 10)`)

Answer (score 2):

Oh java, how good is it open source. from Integer in JDK6:

```
 /**
 * Parses the specified string as a signed decimal integer value. The ASCII
 * character \u002d ('-') is recognized as the minus sign.
 *
 * @param string
 *            the string representation of an integer value.
 * @return the primitive integer value represented by {@code string}.
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 *             if {@code string} cannot be parsed as an integer value.
 */
public static int parseInt(String string) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(string, 10);
}
```

and with radix:

```
/**
 * Parses the specified string as a signed integer value using the specified
 * radix. The ASCII character \u002d ('-') is recognized as the minus sign.
 *
 * @param string
 *            the string representation of an integer value.
 * @param radix
 *            the radix to use when parsing.
 * @return the primitive integer value represented by {@code string} using
 *         {@code radix}.
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 *             if {@code string} cannot be parsed as an integer value,
 *             or {@code radix < Character.MIN_RADIX ||
 *             radix > Character.MAX_RADIX}.
 */
public static int parseInt(String string, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid radix: " + radix);
    }
    if (string == null) {
        throw invalidInt(string);
    }
    int length = string.length(), i = 0;
    if (length == 0) {
        throw invalidInt(string);
    }
    boolean negative = string.charAt(i) == '-';
    if (negative && ++i == length) {
        throw invalidInt(string);
    }

    return parse(string, i, radix, negative);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same function.  `parseInt(String str)` assumes base-10 (unless the string starts with `0x` or `0`).  `parseInt(String str, int radix)` uses the given base.  I haven't looked at the code but I bet the first simply calls `parseInt(str, 10)` (except in those two special cases where it'll use `16` and `8`).